# Selecting the rows with unique values after filtering duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to get the colors that are used by only a sole individual. Using the following sample data:

```
+---------+-------------+
| color   | name        | 
+---------+-------------+
| red     | Jane        | 
| red     | Jane        | 
| red     | Bob         | 
| blue    | David       | 
| blue    | Bill        | 
| green   | Jack        | 
| green   | Jack        | 
| purple  | Jack        | 
| orange  | Dan         | 
+---------+-------------+
```

I got rid of the duplicates with

SELECT color, name 
FROM table
GROUP BY color, name;

```
+---------+-------------+
| color   | name        | 
+---------+-------------+
| red     | Jane        | 
| red     | Bob         | 
| blue    | David       | 
| blue    | Bill        | 
| green   | Jack        | 
| purple  | Jack        | 
| orange  | Dan         |
+---------+-------------+
```

What do I need to do to filter it down further to my desired result set of green, purple, and orange only because only one person was associated with that color?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your condition. What do you mean by `colors that do not share different names with other colors` ? Why is `orange` included?

Comment: Do you mean colors that have exactly one distinct name?

Comment: @DavyM: Yes, sorry for the confusion.  I was trying to think of a very specific way to describe it.  I since made an edit to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by going one step further in your query. Take what you have as a subquery, then use it as the source for a second subquery that counts the number of distinct names that have shown up for each color. Then, it just becomes a select from a result set where the number of unique names was one.

```
SELECT color
FROM (SELECT color, COUNT(name) namecount FROM (SELECT color, name 
          FROM table GROUP BY color, name) t1
      GROUP BY color) t2
WHERE namecount = 1
```

Comment: It works, after adding aliases to the sub-queries, it returned the right colors, but where do I add back the name column that corresponds to the color?

Comment: Use an INNER JOIN of your original query `SELECT color, name FROM table GROUP BY color, name` on the color. That will result in a single name record for only the colors that were in your final list.